# catch TextCtrl's key/char events and forward typed key to the stdin of a subprocess

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, keyboard-events

I am trying to use wx.TextCtrl to catch the typed key events, and directly forward the typed key to the stdin of a subprocess. Please note, for my special purpose, I will
completely disable the text editing feature of the TextCtrl. i.e., when I type a letter, 
the letter will not be appearing on the TextCtrl, it will be directly forwarded.
Here is some code to illustrate what I want.

```
# inside the main frame
    self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
    self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)
# ...

def OnKey(self, evt):
    keycode = evt.GetKeyCode()
    # ENTER

    if keycode == 13:
        self.subprocess.stdin.read("\n") 
    if keycode == 9:
        self.subprocess.stdin.read("\t") 
    if keycode == 8:
        self.subprocess.stdin.read("\b") 
    if keycode == 316:
        pass # maybe some key will be ignored
    else:
        evt.skip()

def OnChar(self, evt):
    key=chr(keycode)                   
    self.subprocess.stdin.read(key)
```

I want to forward "ENTER", "TAB", "BACKSPACE", characters, numbers, etc., all the key input events to stdin, without letting TextCtrl to interfere. Is there a good way to do it? Or I have to explicitely match each key one by one?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you do not want text editing, why use TextCtrl?  StaticText would seem closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to convert the key code to a character:

```
chr(keycode)
```

That won't get everything though, like enters and tabs. You'd have to handle that on a case by case basis (like you do in your example). Otherwise you'll need to create a dictionary of key code to character mappings:

```
codemap = {97:'a', 98:'b', 8:'\b'} # Fill this out
self.subprocess.stdin.read(codemap[keycode])
```

You also might want to play with wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER and wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB. They enable/disable capturing the enter and tab keys as text.